# Docker Image build - source code changes not reflecting

Tags: angular, docker

I used to deploy my angular web app as a docker image to the GCP,
but Ive discovered the issue that whenever I make some changes to my angular source code, a new image rebuild is not reflecting the changes. The serving method for the local environment is executing fine, but the docker image still contains environment vars, console logs and module settings that have been already removed.

I tried also by removing the cache from the build but it didnt work out.
Here are my building commands (im using MB Pro M1)

```
docker system prune --force
docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64 --no-cache -t image .
docker run --platform=linux/amd64 --name container -d -p 8080:80 image
```

Comment: You have pushed the image to the registry GCP is pulling from, yes?

Comment: Yes, but these changes are not even on my local docker container present. I removed every time all container & images, pruned and built afterwards. But aswell as on the cloud and on my local machine the docker container is just keeping the old changes..

Comment: Make sure you clear the browser cache by hitting ctrl-F5 to refresh the site

Comment: @HansKilian doing that all the time ;D

Comment: Please see [mcve]